# react native ble manager BleManager.write function doesn't respond as expected

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-manager

```
const infoConnected = () => {//Show the connected devices
BleManager.getConnectedPeripherals([]).then((results) => {
  if (results.length == 0) {
    console.log('No connected peripherals')
  }
  //for (var i = 0; i < 1;/*list2.length;*/ i++) {//once for now
    console.log("Connected Device Variables:");
  
    //FULL INFO
    let deviceInfo=list2[0];
    console.log(deviceInfo);

    //Split INFO
    console.log("peripheralId INFO:");
    console.log(list2[0].id);

    console.log("serviceUUID INFO:");
    console.log(list2[0].advertising.serviceUUIDs);

    console.log("characteristicUUID INFO:");
    console.log(list2[0].id);

    //write and take a promis
    //const data=stringToBytesToBytes('dsadsa');
    //const dataByte = convertString.UTF8.stringToBytes(data);

    //const data = stringToBytes(String(12345));
    //const dataByte = convertString.UTF8.stringToBytes(data);

    //const data = stringToBytes("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    
    let command = ['XX', '00', 'XX', '00', '00', '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00', 'XX','XX'];
    let data = command.map(x => {return parseInt(x, 16);});

    response=BleManager.write(
      "XX:24:XX:XX:37:XX",
      'XX-0000-1000-8000-XX',
      'XX-0000-1000-8000-XX',
      data,
    )
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`*******************************Sent ${data}`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

      console.log("*******************************Response From Slave(peripheral)="+JSON.stringify(response));

  });



  BleManager.read(
    "4C:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",
    'XX-0000-XXXX-XXXX-XX',
    'XX-0000-XXXX-XXXX-XX'
  )
    .then((readData) => {
      // Success code
      console.log("*******************************Read: " + readData);
  
      buffer = Buffer.Buffer.from(readData); //https://github.com/feross/buffer#convert-arraybuffer-to-buffer
      const sensorData=buffer.readUInt8(1, true);
      console.log("*******************************Buffer read:"+ buffer);
      console.log("*******************************SensorData read:"+sensorData);
      //const sensorData = buffer.readUInt8(1, true);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Failure code
      console.log(error);
    });
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnse2.png)
Hey, I'm new to react native,
I want to use write function to communicate with my bluetooth device.

The return value is;
Response From Slave(peripheral)={"_1":0,"_2":0,"_3":null,"_4":null}

The function above can't communicate with my bluetooth device the response shown below is wrong. Am I doing smt wrong.
Thanks for help :)
[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnse2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your response is an unresolved promise.  Your `.then` block will get the response, but since you're not returning it in that block (or using it), it can't be stored or displayed. Try this instead

```js
  .then(response => {
    console.log(`*******************************Sent ${data}`);
    console.log("*******************************Response From Slave(peripheral)="+JSON.stringify(response));
  });
```

If you want to store the response, consider using async/await syntax; it's a simpler mental model.

```js
  const response = await BleManager.write(
    // ...
  );
  console.log(response);
```

You will have to mark the function this is inside as async, of course.